# Combine AngularJS and Laravel Routing

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, routes, angular-ui-router

I am using AngularJS and Laravel for my web app project. My routing look like this:

AngularJS:

```
angular.config(['$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider',function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: '/admin/dashboard'
        });
}]);
```

Laravel:

```
Route::group(array('prefix'=>'admin', function(){
    Route::get('/', ['as'=>'admin.main',function(){
        return view('main');
    }]);

    Route::get('/dashboard', ['as'=>'admin.dashboard',function(){
        return view('dashboard');
    }]);
});
```

I am facing problem that I would need to declare route path at 2 place. One at Angular and the other one at Laravel. So, every time when I add new route or change route path, I will need to work on 2 place. This will become something tedious and hard to maintain when the app grows.

Is there anyway that I only need to set the route URL at one place, but will be effective for both?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you're building the single-page app. That means on server-side (Laravel) you need to use the same template for all GET requests, e.g.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function() {
    Route::get('(.*)', function() {
        return view('dashboard');
    });
});
```

On client-side (AngularJS) you're doing routing as described in question.

---

Btw, you're using wrong syntax in Laravel routing, this is incorrect:

```
Route::get('/', ['as'=>'admin.main',function(){
}]);
```

and this how it should be:

```
Route::get('/', ['as'=>'admin.main'],function(){
//                                 ^
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 5.4 I was **not** able to define a route using regex as in:

```
Route::get('/account/(.*)', function() { return view('index'); });
```

Instead I had to use a parameter and use regex to ensure it captured all paths:

```
Route::get('/account/{path?}', function() {
    return view('index');
})->with('path', '.*');
```